# VSCode Warning/Error: 'foo' is assigned a value but never used in JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a small snippet on a JavaScript using Visual Studio Code, and I've encountered a warning/error that I find puzzling. In my project, I have three files: `index.php`, `utils.js`, and `index.js`.

Here's the structure of my files:

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JS Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    JS Test
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**utils.js**

```
console.log("utils.js");

const foo = () => {
    console.log('foo');
}
```

**index.js**

```
console.log("index.js");

foo();
```

In Visual Studio Code, I'm receiving a warning or error indicating that 'foo' is assigned a value but never used. However, I am indeed using `foo` in the `index.js` file. Despite this, the warning persists.

I'm seeking clarification on why this warning is appearing and if there's a way to resolve it. I believe I am correctly using the `foo` function, but the IDE seems to think otherwise. Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

This is a small snippet of what I'm trying to do in my actual project. Also I apologize for if any mistake I made in this post.

I tried making this snippet for same case but it didn't work.

EDIT: I'm trying to use jslint/eslint on my project. I don't know if it is possible with vanilla js or not.

Comment: defined in one file, used in another, I don't think ANY javascript linter will pass your code

Comment: Your linter will by default assume that the js files are modules, which have their own local scope, not script files that are running in the global scope. You'll have to change this setting, and probably declare `foo` as a global so that its usage in *index.js* is recognised.

Comment: @JaromandaX So can I assume that the structure I'm trying to build isn't possible/used anywhere? By structure I mean using linting with vanilla js/php project.

Comment: @VivekMakwana it's certainly possible, but the approach of using scripts with globals is a bit outdated, modules are favoured. Which linter are you using?

Comment: why do you keep using the word vanilla in front of javascript? anyway, the code is fine, the linter just won't know it - have you thought of using more modern "vanilla" javascript, like *modules*? The way one uses *modules* means linters would be satisfied

Comment: @Bergi Well it's old codebase without any conventions or standards. I'm trying to use `eslint` with airbnb-base ext.

Comment: See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-globals then